# Full text search including tags

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, search

This isn't entirely exclusive to cakephp but that's the framework im using so any help by thateans would be great..!

I have a MySQL table of posts, tags and post_tags to associate the two together.

I've set up my full text fields on my posts table to be the body and title but I wanted to include the associated tags into my searching too and order the posts based on where the search query mathes any of the tags assigned to the posts.

Would I need to build a hefty SQL query for this perhaps? Also if anyone could offer a cakephp specific solution I'd also like to cache the searches too using the inbuilt cache methods...

Many thanks!

Comment: You'd have to use ad-hoc joins here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "find" function in CakePHP:

```
$result = $this->Post->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Post.body LIKE' => '%search_text%')));
```

If you want more information from a query put this line before "find" function:

```
$this->Post->recursive = 2; //or 1
```

In $result you should get all tags which belongs to the founded Posts.